# Как задать тип данных столбца при создании столбца в JTable?

Tags: java, swing

Хочу при создании столбца по нажатии кнопки из `ComboBox` выбирать тип данных в столбце, но не могу найти ни свойство, ни метод. Подскажите, как менять тип.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так

```
        TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(){
            Class[] types = {String.class,Boolean.class,Integer.class,Double.class};

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }
        };
```

Метод *.class устанавливает тип данных в столбце таблицы. Например `String.class` - это означает что в столбце находятся строки. Соответственно таблица по умолчанию подставит `TableCellRenderer` и `TableCellEditor` для строки, так же столбец будет выполнять сортировку как со строками. Если тип `Integer.class`, то это значит что в столбце целые числа и сортироваться они будут как числа и при отображении по умолчанию они будут выравниваться по правому краю. Для отображения объектов типа `Boolean.class` используется CheckBox и т.д.  Более подробно можно посмотреть здесь [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: Я видел этот метод, и я, видимо, не до конца понимаю, что он делает. Что означает запись `*.class`? В какой момент тип передается какому-то методу или конструктору столбца так, что все элементы в нем становятся одного типа? Или что в этом методе заставляет столбец принимать указанный тип?

Comment: Я добавил в ответ объяснение. В том примере который я написал - создал статический массив с типами и переопределил метод `getColumnClass(int)`, теперь когда данный метод используется моделью, он возвращает значения из заданного мной массива.  Какого поведения таблицы вы пытаетесь добиться?

Comment: Хочу при нажатии на кнопку Добавить столбец открывать диалоговое окно, выбирать из КомбоБокса тип данных в будущем столбце, ввести в текстовое поле имя столбца, нажать окей и тем самым создать столбец с указанными именем и типом.